# How to run16 bit applications on Windows 7

Tags: assembly, windows-7, windows-7-x64, 16-bit, tasm

I need to do assembly programming using TASM. But TASM application is running on 16bit OS.
My PC runs Windows 7 64bit OS. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a virtual machine like : `https://www.virtualbox.org/`, there is also VMware, Microsoft Virtual machine

you install a virtual OS on it (windows 7 32bits, XP, I was running Win98 on it to play old Prince of Persia :p) and do you work normally ;-)

Comment: Other than a VirtualBox, isn't there any way to run the 16bit application directly?

Comment: I don't know, and I think no. See "Igor skochinsky" response but since you're programming in Assembly, there is emu8086 http://www.emu86.com/ where you can write and run your assembly code

Comment: Use Virtual Box or VMware, I'm sure you will need it later ;-)

Answer (score 4):

1. [Windows XP mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7) provides an emulated 32-bit XP install which can run 16-bit NE and DOS programs.
2. [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) is a very good DOS emulator which can run most DOS programs, both real-mode and protected mode. Even Windows 3.x! It can also share a directory with the host so it's very easy to use.
3. [MS-DOS Player](http://homepage3.nifty.com/takeda-toshiya/msdos/) by Toshiya Takeda can run many simple DOS programs, as long as they don't use any exotic DOS or BIOS services. It's very simple to use, just add "msdos" before the command:

   `msdos <program.exe> <arguments>`